# Oracle SQL Developer won't start, says no j2SE SDK

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I just installed Oracle Client 11g R2 on my win 7 machine.  Went OK.  Tried to start SQL Developer.  Got the prompt:

[image]

Navigated to the exe:
[image]

Then got the error message:

[image]

Well, OK the SDK is in a different directory, but that didn't work either:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Significant changes have been made to Java 9 and 10, and it looks like Oracle SQL Developer doesn't recognize Java as Java because of those changes. Try using Java 8.

Comment: That's a really old version of SQL developer. Also, we don't support Java 10 yet. Latest version of SQL developer needs Java 8. Your version probably is expecting Java 6

Comment: Thought about v6, but found no way to download it.  do you know?

Comment: Just do what @littlefoot suggests below

Comment: Wish I could!  I'm on a corporate desktop and that version of SQL Developer comes with 11g, which is the current approved Oracle version for the work I'm doing.  I'll see if I can influence the big wigs to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself the pain & time; go to [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), download & install `Windows 64-bit with JDK 8 included` version.